# How to pass variables to a modal from a link

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a navigation bar with some links. The links all trigger the same modal but I need to display different information inside the modal based on the link. I'd prefer a non-jQuery solution but if it is necessary I'll take it.

I tried this...

**firstpage.php**

```
    <li><a href="#theModal?viewmessages=mymessages" data-toggle="modal">My Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#theModal?viewnotifications=mynotifications" data-toggle="modal">My Notifications</a></li>

<!---Modal -->
  <div id="theModal" class="modal fade text-center">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <?php include 'modal.php';?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <!-- Modal -->
```

**modal.php**

```
<!--
=============================
ISSET_GET MESSAGES 
=============================-->
<div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Messages</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>some text here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
<!--
=============================
ISSET_GET NOTIFICATIONS
=============================-->
<div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Notifications</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>some text here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: What data are you trying to pass to the modals?

Comment: variables set in `firstpage.php` should be accessible in `modal.php`. how much of the content needs to change? You could just have all your modals at the bottom of your page. and in your links set `data-target="#the-id-of-your-modal"` in each of your links. check out my example https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEWFXWWS2918

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should render all of your modals at the bottom of the page and use jQuery to to load the modal associated to the link.

e.g.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn1">Open Modal 1</button>
```

Then bind bootstraps .modal() function to  the button's click event with jQuery. This is where you can set which modal to load eg.

```
$("#myBtn1").click(function(){
    $("#myModal1").modal();
});
```

Please run my code snippet which I have modified from w3 schools documentation

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Activate multiple Modal with JavaScript</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn1">Open Modal 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="myBtn2">Open Modal 2</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Look its modal one</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">look its modal 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn1").click(function(){
        $("#myModal1").modal();
    });
    $("#myBtn2").click(function(){
        $("#myModal2").modal();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

original source of code that I modified:

> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_js&stacked=h